# CAB (Contextual Action Bar)

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

I have one question and my question was "Can we show the default FIND function in CAB on actionbar by clicking the button or action item on action bar?". Please your ideas

Comment: What's wrong with DrawerLayout? http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: try [this](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have use [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) for my application...have a look

Comment: This could be a comment, not an answer.